# How do can you make redirect_to use a different HTTP request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, http-request

At the end of one of my controller actions I need to redirect to a page that only accepts put requests. I have been trying to figure out how to get redirect_to to use a put request but to no success.

Is this possible? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution to my problem. I found a very good write up on the situation [here](http://last10percent.com/2008/05/26/post-redirects-in-rails/). My implementation looks like this:

```
private
def redirect_post(redirect_post_params)
  controller_name = redirect_post_params[:controller]
  controller = "#{controller_name.camelize}Controller".constantize
  # Throw out existing params and merge the stored ones
  request.parameters.reject! { true }
  request.parameters.merge!(redirect_post_params)
  controller.process(request, response)
  if response.redirected_to
    @performed_redirect = true
  else
    @performed_render = true
  end
end
```

Then I called this method like this:

```
  redirect_post :controller => 'registrations', :action => 'order', :_method => 'put', :authenticity_token => params[:authenticity_token]
```

So I was able to 'fake' a put request by making a post request (using `redirect_post`) and then assigning 'put' to a `_method` param. If you look at a normal `put` request all it is a `post` from a form with a `_method` param. So its a bit hackish but it gets the job done.

Also, you have to make sure that when you call `redirect_post` the values of your hash are strings otherwise errors will be thrown.

Comment: `controller.process` doesn't work anymore in rails 4

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you are able to do this, and I suspect that the limitation is part of HTTP itself.

When using **redirect_to**  - the redirection happens as a "302 Moved" header unless otherwise specified in the parameters.

Having a look at the HTTP Spec itself doesn't reveal any way to change the type of request the browser makes via redirect.

[HTTP Redirects](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3):

> This class of status code indicates
>   that further action needs to be taken
>   by the user agent in order to fulfill
>   the request. The action required MAY
>   be carried out by the user agent
>   without interaction with the user if
>   and only if the method used in the
>   second request is GET or HEAD.

I think you may need to use JavaScript to achieve this functionality, or perhaps rethink the flow of control in your application.

Answer (score 3):

If the action is in the same controller as where you're trying to redirect from, simply call the action and render the template like so:

```
def show
  index
  render :action => "index"
end
```

If it's not, then I don't know how you do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect to a different page that issues the put request from the client, [using Javascript](http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2007/03/18/not-just-get-and-post-http-put-and-delete-with-javascript/).